# OpenCV removing the background with a mask image

Tags: python, objective-c, opencv

Given two input i. original image & ii. mask image, what's the best way to remove to the background from the original image.

**Original Image**

[image]

**Mask Image**

[image]

The final output would contain just the dog without the background and look transparent. I have seen the mask images are also created with OpenCV. Is there a way to just the existing mask image and generate the output image?

**Update**
I tried this

```
import cv2

# opencv loads the image in BGR, convert it to RGB
img = cv2.imread("originalImage.png")
mask = cv2.imread("maskImage.png")
final = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)
cv2.imwrite("final.png", final)
```

**Final Image**

[image]

Is there a way to set the background to be transparent?

Comment: @Baraa Thanks for the immediate response. I tried your suggestion and the background is not transparent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a transparent image by creating a 4-channel BGRA image and copying the first 3 channels from the original image and setting the alpha channel using the mask image.

```
transparent = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 4), dtype=np.uint8)
transparent[:,:,0:3] = img
transparent[:, :, 3] = mask
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick update @Baraa Ran into this error - `transparent[:, :, 3] = mask
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (170,273,3) into shape (170,273)`

Comment: Please make sure that your mask is a single-channel image. You can use: `mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way in Python OpenCV. Convert the image to BGRA and then insert the alpha channel.

```
result = img.copy()
result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
result[:, :, 3] = mask
```

Answer (score 1):

Add alpha channel to your input image and copy mask into it.

```
Mat img;
cvtColor(imread("img.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR), img , cv::COLOR_RGB2RGBA);
Mat mask = imread("mask.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
for(int r = 0; r < img.rows; r++){
    for(int c = 0; c < img.cols; c++){
        uchar alpha = 0;
        if(r < mask.rows && c < mask.cols)
            alpha = mask.at<uchar>(r, c);
        img.at<Vec4b>(r, c)[3] = alpha;
    }
}
imwrite("result.png", img);
```

Btw your image doesn't have the same resolution as your mask, but still the result looks ok.

(I know it's not Python but there is c++ tag so... :D)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using PIL:

```
def remove_background_to_alpha(image_path: str, mask_path: str) -> bytes:
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    mask = Image.open(mask_path)
    image = image.convert("RGBA")
    mask = mask.convert("L")
    image.putalpha(mask)
    image.save("result.png", format="PNG")
```